# Rewriting basic URL using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm hopeless at mod_rewrite definitions as I'm looking for someone to help me with this basic query.

I have a URL say `http://localhost/foobar/`
I would like to rewrite the URL so that `foobar` is removed.

So `http://localhost/foobar/barfoo.jpg` points to `http://localhost/barfoo.jpg`
and `http://localhost/foobar/foo/bar/` points to `http://localhost/foo/bar`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file in that folder, Just add a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/foobar/(.*)$ /$1 [NC]
```

And that will do the job.

Hey by the way, try to google a bit, there are tons of answers for such simple things **`;)`**